# How to modify a list in ReactJS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list

In my application, I have a list of users (email, first name and last name) that I want to display. I must be able to modify them.

I use an onChange on every input field, I have to store the current field I change and modify it in my list, look like:

```
{uuid: "1883dbae-9d3d-4c2b-840c-10efa39b9be3", email: "usertest@gmail.com", first_name: "U", last_name: "T"}
{uuid: "afc498dc-308f-4cf7-91d0-5933c4ef85f2", email: "X@XX.com", first_name: "X", last_name: "XX"}
{uuid: "b4595ed4-af5d-46ca-b480-2bc4ac8d61dc", email: "test@at.dot", first_name: "test", last_name: "test"}
{uuid: "af69c46b-0928-4c2e-b190-334b24964fb5", email: "admin@xxx.com", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
```

I don't find in reactjs how to modifiy, per example, just modify only the `first_name` of the first line.

My full code of my page: https://hastebin.com/baguteruki.cs

Comment: So what you've done yourself?

Comment: @ummahusla All I tried was failure, the last is in comment on my full code (Link in my post)

Comment: I don't think that I can login to this link due to proxy/vpn issues. It's a good practice to put the main methods inside the question.

Comment: The issue is fixed, correct response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you look for the item you want to modify with some kind of id. You could use the uuid for this.

```
changeName(id, newName) {
  users.forEach(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      user.first_name = newName;
    }
  });
}
```